# Inserting greek character directly on TexStudio editor

Tags: texstudio

Well, this is certainly a very specific question, and not a LaTeX one, rather a TexStudio question.

I use Kubuntu. I have configured my keyboard, so that when I press a certain combination of keys, I can directly type greek letters, as in [AltGr] + [¿], and then [a], i get an α (alpha). This is what is called *dead greek* (just like when you write an accented vowel (á, for example) and this is called *dead acute*, for the acute accent ´).

The thing is, I can write greek letters all over my computer, except on all TexStudio (every single place you can type in). I have tried changing where the "trigger" ([¿] key) is located (to [0], for example) and I can't seem to write in greek on the editor, it just does nothing (copying and pasting greek from other places works fine).

And no, it is not a font issue, the font I use with TexStudio, worked just fine with greek on Texmaker.

It is certainly not a big issue, but it is something that I didn't expect to happen. I use TexStudio 3.0.4 AppImage version (latest version, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: There are some (older) bug reports related to this, for example https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/690/ and https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/555/. Could also be https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#i-cannot-type-certain-characters-on-my-keyboard-that-involve-altgr-on-windows (that says Windows, but I guess the issue is the same for Kubuntu). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298923/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-key. Posting a bug yourself on the TexStudio bug tracker may help.

Answer (score 1):

**"SOLVED"**

Okay, so I was able to "solve" the issue (well, actually didn't solve anything). Based on Marijn's comment, I figured that an old Qt version could be the culprit. So I checked and the AppImage version uses an old Qt version 5.6, if I remember correctly. So I downloaded and installed the corresponding pre-packed version, with Qt 5.14, and it works just fine.